# Where is Object Loader found in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I've only used the Simple Loader in ArcCatalog.

**[The documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_loading_data_into_existing_feature_classes_and_tables/003n0000003r000000/)** also mentions an Object Loader which resides in ArcMap.

Where do I find this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via the Context Menu (right click on the grey area right on file, edit menu)

Customise GUI pops up.

Select Commands Tab

Click and drag the Load Objects

[image]

Full Official Documentation

Should work with all version of ArcGIS

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/18202\